# scala - getting java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala

getting java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
val data3 = data2.filter(x => type1_dm_med.contains(x._2._1.last.medicine))
```

when I try to `print data3.count` I get below error - not sure how to fix it, please help

```
[Stage 50:=====> (20 + 1) / 200]16/02/26 01:37:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 22.0 in stage 50.0 (TID 1636)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.last(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:135)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.last(List.scala:84)
```

more context:

```
 class Diagnostic(patientID:String, date: Date, code: String)
 class Medication(patientID: String, date: Date, medicine: String)
```

loaded data from .csv into medication:RDD[Medication] and diagnostic:
 RDD[Diagnostic]

```
val mpairs = medication.map(x=>(x.patientID,x))
val dpairs = diagnostic.map(x=>(x.patientID,x))
val data = mpairs.fullOuterJoin(dpairs)
```

'data' tuple example:
(000496120-01,(Some(Medication(000496120-01,Fri Jul 01 15:15:00 EDT 2005,protamine sulfate)),Some(Diagnostic(000496120-01,Mon Jan 07 15:00:00 EST 2013,v70.0))))

type1_dm_dx et'al are list of code or medicines that want to filter on

```
val cond1 = data.filter(x => type1_dm_dx.contains(x._2._2.last.code))
val data1 = data.subtractByKey(cond1)
val data2 = data1.filter(x => type2_dm_dx.contains(x._2._2.last.code))
val data3 = data2.filter(x => type1_dm_med.contains(x._2._1.last.medicine))
```

hope this helps

Comment: beside your question, `x._2._1` this looks suspicious and like unreadable code/bad practice. You may read about `case class`es.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more context for more meaningful help. All I can glean is that it looks like whatever `x._2._1` is an empty `List` and as a result calling `.last` on it throws an error.

Comment: provided more context

Answer (score 2):

Calling `last` on an empty `List` will cause this exception to be thrown.

You could write your filter predicate to safely handle an empty list, by using `lastOption`, for example:

```
x => x._2._1.lastOption.exists(y => type1_dm_med.contains(y.medicine))
```

Comment: added more context - see the problem definition again - your suggestions ensures there is no error anymore but the filter is not happening correctly

Comment: you rock - I was making a coding error - in fact your suggestion works - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Count, counts how many items are in a collection, for that equals returns true. You may want to use `size` or to pass a item to count.

## EDIT

In addition to your editing:
Bens solution is beautiful, but you could write

```
x => x._2._1.nonEmpty && type1_dm_med.contains(x._2._1.last.medicine)
```

as well. It may makes your code more readable, depends on the context.
You should consider to use something else then tupels as well. A `class` or `case class` would make your code more readable then `x._2._1.`
If you want to use a tupel, `case class` is often the better solution. You can think about a `case class` like a named tupel. It fits the same needs, but is more readable.